# Multiply form td by input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, with a table inside.
Each row 4 columns:

1. Item Name
2. Item Price (this is set by me, not user)
3. Quantity (set by user input)
4. Total (price*qty)

I want it to reflect totals live.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uyyzkLny/

Code Snippet:

```
 <tr class="txtMult">
        <td>Salmon</td>
        <td class="val1" type="number">28</td>
        <td><input name="Fish1" class="val2" size="2px"/></td>
        <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
    </tr>
```

--

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
               // get the values from this row:
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
               $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }
  });
```

Issue:
Keep getting 0. (or NaN).  From what I know about Jquery, the issue is that I'm treating val1 as user input instead of hard-coded.  How do I fix that?   Is that the problem?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.val` on a `td`, so you need to get the `.text()` of the element, and parse it as an integer (optional, but a good idea):

```
var $val1 = parseInt($('.val1', this).text())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyyzkLny/2/

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Will accept answer when I can :) (5 minutes from now)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that will give you a start - just a different approach - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/3r9j41be/).

Key points:

uses HTML limiters to keep number to an integer between 0 and 10

'$' is stripped off for the calculation and then put back for the total.

JS

```
$('input[type=number]').change( function(){
    $('.mytable tr td:nth-child(2)').each( function(index, element){
             var price = $(this).text().slice(1);
             var number = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val();
             var total = (price * number).toFixed(2);
             $(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').text('$' + total );
             console.log(price + ' *** ' + number + ' *** ' + total);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.val1', this).text()
```

instead of

```
$('.val1', this).val();
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uyyzkLny/4/)